# dependency injection, circular dependency in stuartsierra/component for a monitoring component

Tags: dependency-injection, clojure, health-monitoring

I have a circular dependency problem with my [StuartSierra/component](https://github.com/stuartsierra/component) components.

I have:

- a `webServer` component
- a `Healthcheck` component, that periodically walks the system to find components implementing a `healthcheck` protocol. It is part of the monitoring.
- a database, job queue connection etc. components that implement the `healthcheck` protocol.

`WebServer` implements the `healthcheck` protocol as well.

I have a function that given a system returns compojure routes, allowing to query the last healthckeck status, stored in the healthcheck component.

So I have this circular dependency with a workaround in this function for now, which is to take the system as a `var` and dereference it when needed, instead of taking it as a value.

But this is inconvenient, and means that during startup the check will report an incorrect value for a little while.

Is there a way to handle this kind of lifecycle in component? Or is there a design flaw in here?

Answer (score 2):

As usual with circular dependencies, you can resolve this by extracting some of the troublesome functionality into one or more additional components to break the cycle. One approach would be to rename the "webserver" component to "app handler" or something, and have it include all the routes except for the monitoring-based routes. It should not actually start the webserver itself, just present a ring handler function that you could use to start a server.

At this point, adding a "monitoring" component that depends on the app handler is easy, of course, and it can produce health status for the whole system (except the webserver itself, which we haven't gotten to yet).

Finally a new "webserver" component can take the routes provided by the app handler, and start up a webserver that combines them with an additional `/monitoring` handler or whatever, which asks the monitoring component how things are doing. You can add status about the webserver itself here if you like, although really if the webserver is unhealthy you will in many cases not be able to say anything useful about it via the webserver itself.

A diagram summarizing the component dependency graph:

> http://svgur.com/i/1GY.svg

Evidently Stack Overflow does not support embedding SVG files, so I had to host it externally.

---

A completely different approach you could take would be to have the monitoring component have no dependencies at all, but instead be plugin/registration based. Each other system would depend on the monitoring system, and as part of its startup it would register itself by providing some callback to answer the question "how healthy am I?"

In some ways I think this goes against the spirit of Component, since you are adding implicit backwards edges to the dependency graph, but I think it is a reasonable approach. It's more evidence of the old adage that "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection". In C and such languages this usually meant another level of pointer; in functional languages it usually means replacing a value with a function.

Comment: "It should not actually start the webserver itself, just present a ring handler function that you could use to start a server.". I am not sure how that would look like? https://gist.github.com/nha/fa42e22fdad1446d97e96976e382fd0f

Comment: I was describing something more like https://gist.github.com/amalloy/f281723c6700c1da1cd9905e18e08d83 (I don't know the actual syntax for a component system-map, so obviously this is a sketch).

Comment: In your sketch, is `monitoring` `health-check`?
I tried something similar, but component seems to want maps instead of functions (search for "would be started as if you did this" in it's README), only when injecting dependencies.
Side note: "in functional languages it usually means replacing a value with a function." Never thought about these like that, interesting!